# How to use $ne for getting data using mongodb java for document with array.?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java

$ne in momgodb using java not giving proper result. Am i missing something?
My database is as below.
[image]

Which contains value where `mac_address = "-".`

My code for retrieving records where `mac_address != "-"` is as,

```
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject("mac_address", new BasicDBObject("$ne", "-"));
DBCursor cursor = node_info.find(whereQuery);
```

It's returning all the records. What can be probably wrong.?

**Update**
i converted your suggested query as follow. what's wrong in this?

```
    BasicDBObject unwind= new BasicDBObject("$unwind","$nodes");
    BasicDBObject mac = new BasicDBObject("mac_address", "$nodes.mac_address");
    BasicDBObject projection= new BasicDBObject("$project",mac);
    BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new     BasicDBObject("mac_address",notEqual));
   node_info.aggregate(unwind, projection, match);
```

Sorry i am not much familiar with mongodb query.

Comment: Did you assign the result of `node_info.aggregate(..)` to `DBCursor` variable?

Comment: No. return type of aggregate function is AggreggationOutput. i can't do that.

Comment: Okay, assign it to `AggregationOutput` and then investigate if the desired data is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, the `nodes` is a nested array and you're not property querying it.

In order to filter by a property of a nested array, you have to use the `$elemMatch` operator. By documentation:

> The `$elemMatch` operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

So, this query should be working:

```
db.node_info.find({ 
  nodes : { 
    $elemMatch : { 
      mac_address : { $ne : "-" } 
    } 
  }
})
```

This query has to be *translated* to a `BasicDBObject` with which you would work in Java. It should be something like:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject notEqual = new BasicDBObject("$ne", "-");
BasicDBObject macCriteria = new BasicDBObject("mac_address", notEqual);
BasicDBObject elemMatch = new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch, macCriteria);
query.put("nodes", elemMatch);
```

---

**Update**:

The problem with the solution above is that the query will actually return all the `node_info` documents that match the provided criteria and **will** include the nested array documents that do not match the criteria.

In order to return **only** the nested array documents, for which `mac_accress != "-"`, you have to do aggregation. The aggregation query in Mongo would be:

```
db.node_info.aggregate([
    { $unwind : "$nodes" },
    { $project : { mac : "$nodes.mac_address" } },
    { $match : { mac : { $ne : "-" } } }
])
```

This will return only the documents, for which the `mac_address` is not `"-"`. Of course, you select other fields of the documents to be included in the result. In order to do so, you have to enumerate the desired fields in the `$project` pipeline stage
.

Also, this query has to be *translated* in `BasicDBObject` object(s), but this can be done similarly to above.

Comment: @HiteshVaghani As an additional info: You were querying for `mac_address` fields in the root of each document. Since your documents don't seem to have that field, it evaluates to `null`, which *is* not equal `-`, hence all documents are returned.

Comment: I tried this query { "nodes" : { "$elemMatch" : { "mac_address" : { "$ne" : "-"}}}}. This is giving the same result as before.

Comment: @HiteshVaghani, that's actually what is supposed to happen, because we're querying documents from `node_info` that match some criteria. We've never specified that we want *some* of the nested documents in the array, we just specified that we want all the `node_info` document, in which nested array there's some object that meets some criteria.

Comment: @kocko Exactly i got the problem. Thanks. Tried to solve it but hadn't succeeded.

Comment: @kocko please checkout my update.

Comment: @kocko: please look at this question. Same problem arise again.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600055/mongodb-remove-query-using-java-not-working