# What is wrong with MongoDB remove query using mongodb java for sub-array of document?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java

Remove in momgodb using java not giving proper result. Am i missing something?
My database is as below.
[image]

My code for removeing records where `index = "7"` is as,

```
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject("nodes.index", new BasicDBObject("$eq", "7"));
node_info.remove(whereQuery);
```

It's returning all the records and deleting my complete database. What can be probably wrong.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of remove try [$pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) method code as below

```
BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("_id", object id here);
BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject("nodes", new BasicDBObject("index", 7)))
node_info.update(match, new BasicDBObject("$pull", update);
```

Comment: Superb. Thank you very much. _id is auto-generated so i used match = node_info.findOne() instead of your query. than works well.

Comment: #yogesh please have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625241/finding-document-with-mongodb-using-java